# Using JQuery dialog to redirect on confirm when the redirect call is within a button click event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, redirect, webforms

I'm coming to believe this isn't going to be possible, but I thought I'd ask before scrapping the idea. Id like to have an asp button control with an on click event, that when clicked will redirect the user back to various menus (dependent on the page) However, I'd like to display the JQuery dialog to get the users confirmation so they understand changes won't be saved.

I don't want to use JavaScript or Jquery to call the redirect (which is why I believe this isn't going to be possible), as the URL is going to change and from what I've been told passing in a URL to a javascript redirect is a big no-no in terms of security.

**Is this actually possible?** I've tried returning from the dialog but that isn't going to work as its asynchronous and the redirect happens before its even opened.

So this is what I have:

```
         $(function () {          
             $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,
                 resizable: false,
                 height: "auto",
                 width: 400,
                 modal: true,
                 buttons: {
                     "Confirm": function () {
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     },
                     Cancel: function () {
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
                 }
             });

             $(".exit-button").click(function () {
                 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
             });            
         });
```

Comment: "passing in a URL to a javascript redirect is a big no-no in terms of security." Why? Javascript can of course send the user to another page. Is it because you want to include some data which would have to go onto the querystring? Probably what you want to do is make the "Confirm" button of the dialog cause the page to postback with the equivalent status as if the button had posted back directly. I think there's stuff on google showing how to do this already with webforms (more complicated than it ought to be, due the convulated way webforms works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround. You can have a server button and put a css class on it to make it hidden. And put a client button, on click of this client button you will show the dialog. In the dialog confirm button click you can trigger the click of server button by jquery[`$("#server-button-click-id").click();`].

Comment: Hi, thank you for the alternative method which I'm pretty sure would work quite well. However, I've decided to use ADyson's approach for now but I'm becoming more inclined to create my own custom popup dialog.